# PHP : How to convert a Windows FILETIME String from LDAP into a readable DATE?

Tags: php, date, datetime, ldap

I'm querying MS LDAP and some date fields about user have this kind of value : `132497313049180481`.

It seems to be in the **Windows FILETIME** format that is use for some informations in LDAP and Active Directory as a **timestamp**.

How to convert it into a readable DATE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **convert Windows FILETIME** (ex: `132497313049180481`) **to a human readable datetime** (in this case: "2020-11-13 08:55:04").

**I hope it can be usefull :**

```
$filetime = "132497313049180481";
echo filetimeToStr($filetime); // Will display "2020-11-13 08:55:04"

function filetimeToStr($filetime){
  date_default_timezone_set ("UTC"); //For a result not depending on server time zone.
  $resp = (int)($filetime / 10000000); //Number of seconds since 1601-01-01.
  $diff = 11644473600; //Number of seconds between FILETIME & Unix timestamp.
  $resp = $resp - $diff; //Actual Unix timestamp matching your filetime.
  $resp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $resp);
  return $resp;
}
```

**Wanna know where the 11644473600 come from ?**

MSDN say that FILETIME :

> Contains a 64-bit value representing the number of 100-nanosecond
> intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC). https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-be/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-filetime?redirectedfrom=MSDN

About Unix timestamp :

> Unix epoch is the time 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970 ... every day is
> treated as if it contains exactly 86400 seconds.
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

```
date_default_timezone_set ("UTC"); //For a result not depending on server time zone.
$start_date = date_create("1601-01-01");
$end_date = date_create("1970-01-01");
$diff = date_diff($start_date, $end_date);
$diff = (int)$diff->format("%a"); //Number of days between FILETIME & Unix timestamp
$diff = ($diff * 86400); //Number of seconds between FILETIME & Unix timestamp
echo $diff; //Will display 11644473600
```

### EDITED

Added `date_default_timezone_set ("UTC");` for a result not depending on server time zone (Thanks @jspit).

Comment: Have you just reposted your answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/64818470/1213708?

Comment: Hello, yes, the title of the question mentioned C# and question was about php. Also the accepted answer was a simple link with no code solution. I didn't find a complete solution to my described problem on the web so I wanted to add a Q&A here with the exact problem I encounter (more presice then the previous one) so it help other people. I'm new here I hope I didn't do wrong. Have a nice day.

Comment: For a result "2020-11-13 08:55:04" must a date_default_timezone_set ('UTC');  to be added. If the server is set to a different time zone, the result of your function will be different.
I like that your solution is also explained in detail.
Rated your answer useful.

Comment: Thanks A LOT @jspit , I edited my answer to add this precious part.

Comment: Please close new duplicates and add new/valuable/unique insights to old answers so that researchers don't have to compare multiple pages to compare answers.

Answer (score 0):

The createDateTimeFromSystemTime() function returns a DateTime object. It can be used universally and also works under 32-bit systems. With other parameters for $basis and $resolution, this function can also process other time stamps (LabVIEW Timestamp, Mac Timestamp ..)

```
function createDateTimeFromSystemTime(
  $time,  //num.String, integer or float
  $basis = '1601-1-1',
  $resolution = 1.E-7,
  $timeZone = 'UTC'
){
  return date_create($basis.' UTC')
    ->modify(round($time * $resolution).' Seconds')
    ->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($timeZone));
}
```

How to use for LDAP-Timestamp:

```
$ldapTimestamp = "132497313049180481";

$dateTime = createDateTimeFromSystemTime($ldapTimestamp);

echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s T');
//2020-11-13 08:55:05 UTC
```

The algorithm is from this [class](https://github.com/jspit-de/dt).

Comment: Please close new duplicates and add new/valuable/unique insights to old answers so that researchers don't have to compare multiple pages to compare answers.